# How to schedule an app to run at a specific time?

Tags: automator

Can I use Automator to make an app to automatically run at, say, 12:00 pm everyday?

Comment: Most apps open up top a Window which waits for user input. Does your app just run and exit when you start it?

Comment: Use a cron job.

Write the command to run in a file like

`0 12 * * * python3 script.py`

and run 

`crontab file.txt`

Check by `crontab -l`, stop the cron by `crontab -r`.

See https://crontab.guru/ also